# Ontario Buildings Data

Tags: data, buffer, canada

I am looking for a buildings layer for Ontario, particularly the Chatham-Kent area to properly assess setback for wind turbine development in the region.  Currently, I am utilizing the buildings data provided on Geogratis; however, I would like to know it's accuracy and if other buildings data is available free or for purchase.

Comment: http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=14/42.4004/-82.1850 has some buildings but geogratis is your best source for free.

Answer (score 1):

You could always contact the regional GIS authority (Essex County) for these types of data sets. Or the municipality/town directly. They would most likely have the most updated/accurate building structures.

[Chatham-Kent GIS viewer and request form](https://www.chatham-kent.ca/gis-services)

[County of Essex GIS](https://www.countyofessex.on.ca/en/residents/maps.asp)